# Selecting Year over year sales data grouped on product name making sure to get products contained only in 1 year

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm attempting to get year over year data. While I can do something like this

```
SELECT tbl_products.product_name, SUM(tbl_invoice_details.quantity- IFNULL(tbl_invoice_details.quantity_returned,0)), 
MONTH(tbl_invoice.invoice_date) as `month`, sort_order
FROM
   tbl_invoice_details
   INNER JOIN tbl_invoice ON tbl_invoice_details.invoice_ID = tbl_invoice.invoice_ID
   INNER JOIN tbl_products ON tbl_products.product_ID = tbl_invoice_details.product_ID
WHERE tbl_invoice.invoice_date BETWEEN  '2016-01-01' AND '2016-07-01'
GROUP BY  `month`, product_name, sort_order
order by `month`, sort_order
```

and run it twice (one for each year). But if there are products with sales in one year but not in the other it's going to cause me problems when creating the charts. I could fix it in code on the backend but it seems that would waste a lot of cycles. I could also first `select distinct` on the products over both years and use that result in the backend to run a query on each product but that would be a ton of database calls. Does anyone know a better way to do this in mySql?

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing everything, but what's wrong with selecting both years and adding the year to the `group by` clause?  If you need to ensure the months exist for both years, it's best to use a `dates` table and `outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can change the `where` clause:

```
SELECT p.product_name, SUM(id.quantity -  IFNULL(id.quantity_returned,0)), 
       YEAR(i.invoice_date) as ayyyy, MONTH(i.invoice_date) as `month`, sort_order
FROM tbl_invoice_details id INNER JOIN
     tbl_invoice i
     ON id.invoice_ID = i.invoice_ID INNER JOIN
     tbl_products p
     ON p.product_ID = id.product_ID
WHERE month(i.invoice_date) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) AND
      year(i.invoice_date) IN (2015, 2016)
GROUP BY  YEAR(i.invoice_date), `month`, product_name, sort_order
ORDER BY yyyy, `month`, sort_order;
```

EDIT:

You might want to put ttwo columns for the values:

```
SELECT p.product_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.voice_date) = 2015 THEN id.quantity -  COALESCE(id.quantity_returned, 0) END)  as val_2015,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(i.voice_date) = 2016 THEN id.quantity -  COALESCE(id.quantity_returned, 0) END)  as val_2016,
       MONTH(i.invoice_date) as `month`, sort_order
FROM tbl_invoice_details id INNER JOIN
     tbl_invoice i
     ON id.invoice_ID = i.invoice_ID INNER JOIN
     tbl_products p
     ON p.product_ID = id.product_ID
WHERE month(i.invoice_date) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) AND
      year(i.invoice_date) IN (2015, 2016)
GROUP BY  YEAR(i.invoice_date), `month`, product_name, sort_order
ORDER BY yyyy, `month`, sort_order;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a dates table and cannot create one then a bunch of unions might help.for example

```
/*
DROP TABLE TBL_PRODUCTS;
CREATE TABLE TBL_PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID INT,PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO TBL_PRODUCTS VALUES
(1,'ABC'), (2,'DEF');
CREATE TABLE TBL_INVOICE(INVOICE_ID INT,INVOICE_DATE DATE);
INSERT INTO TBL_INVOICE VALUES
(1,'2015-06-01'), (2,'2015-07-01'),(3,'2015-08-01'),
(4,'2016-01-01'), (5,'2016-02-01'),(6,'2016-03-01');
DROP TABLE TBL_INVOICE_DETAILS;
CREATE TABLE TBL_INVOICE_DETAILS (INVOICE_ID INT,PRODUCT_ID INT,QUANTITY INT,QUANTITY_RETURNED INT);
INSERT INTO TBL_INVOICE_DETAILS VALUES
(1,1,10,NULL), (2,1,10,NULL),(3,2,10,NULL),
(4,1,10,NULL), (5,1,10,NULL),(6,2,10,NULL);
*/
USE SANDBOX;
SELECT S.product_name, SUM(S.quantity -  IFNULL(S.quantity_returned,0)) NET, 
       S.yyyy, S.`month`
FROM
(
SELECT p.product_name, id.quantity ,id.quantity_returned, 
       YEAR(i.invoice_date) as yyyy, MONTH(i.invoice_date) as `month`
FROM       tbl_invoice_details id 
INNER JOIN tbl_invoice i  ON id.invoice_ID = i.invoice_ID 
INNER JOIN tbl_products p ON p.product_ID = id.product_ID
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,1 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P 
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,2 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,3 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,4 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,5 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,6 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,7 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,8 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,9 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,10 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,11 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2015,12 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,1 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,2 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,3 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,4 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,5 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,6 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,7 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,8 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,9 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,10 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,11 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P
UNION   SELECT  P.PRODUCT_NAME,0,0,2016,12 FROM TBL_PRODUCTS P

) S
WHERE   S.YYYY IN (2015,2016)
GROUP   BY S.PRODUCT_NAME,S.YYYY,S.`MONTH`
```

which returns a result set for every product for every month even if there is no invoice like this

```
+--------------+------+------+-------+
| product_name | NET  | yyyy | month |
+--------------+------+------+-------+
| ABC          |    0 | 2015 |     1 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2015 |     2 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2015 |     3 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2015 |     4 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2015 |     5 |
| ABC          |   10 | 2015 |     6 |
| ABC          |   10 | 2015 |     7 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2015 |     8 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2015 |     9 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2015 |    10 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2015 |    11 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2015 |    12 |
| ABC          |   10 | 2016 |     1 |
| ABC          |   10 | 2016 |     2 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2016 |     3 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2016 |     4 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2016 |     5 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2016 |     6 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2016 |     7 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2016 |     8 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2016 |     9 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2016 |    10 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2016 |    11 |
| ABC          |    0 | 2016 |    12 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |     1 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |     2 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |     3 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |     4 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |     5 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |     6 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |     7 |
| DEF          |   10 | 2015 |     8 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |     9 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |    10 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |    11 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2015 |    12 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |     1 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |     2 |
| DEF          |   10 | 2016 |     3 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |     4 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |     5 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |     6 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |     7 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |     8 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |     9 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |    10 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |    11 |
| DEF          |    0 | 2016 |    12 |
+--------------+------+------+-------+
48 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```